# how to make NestJS with nx work using ESM

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, es6-modules, nrwl-nx

this is example with pure nestjs working fine https://github.com/robertIsaac/nest-esm

this is example with nestjs with nx not working https://github.com/robertIsaac/nx-nest-esm

I already opened an issue in nx https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/19618, it has been a month without them fixing it and saying more weeks are needed and gave a workaround that still doesn't work

how to reproduce

1. create an new nx workspace using `npx create-nx-workspace@latest`
2. add `"type": "module"` in the root `package.json`

Comment: [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -> **TLDR: No**. Please update the question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources for more info.

Comment: @Reyno I have added reproduce steps, there is literally no code example, a newly created empty project won't work